# How to include image into domain model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

With Asp.Net MVC,  need help on building domain model, specifically a binary data type (ie. image) field.  How would I consume [use] said domain model field on the View?

Comment: You can store the image as a binary object(var binary)

Comment: should i convert binary type in order to input image in view?

Answer (score 0):

> how to create field for image (like decimal type Price for good's price and text field for description).

In your domain model create a class with properties like String Filename... Etc and for the image content use Byte[].

> And how to transfer this image to the View?
>   Just bind the byte array to the image tag in html.

For more direction see [images in asp.net Mvc.](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/259/asp-net-mvc-5-with-ef-6-working-with-files)

Answer (score 0):

If you have binary object in your controller and want it to be used and represented in View you could render image using Razor like this

```
public class ImageController : Controller
{
    public Index ()
    {
        return View(new byte[]);
    }
}
```

And your Index.cshtml view should look like this(hence C#6):

```
@model byte[]
@{ var imgSrc = $"data:image/gif;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(Model)}";}
<img src="@imgSrc" style="height: 100px;" />
```